# directory listing is showing "+" sign

Tags: linux, command-line

In one of my directory listing I get following output:

`drwxrws---+  7 sip          sip            4096 Aug  5 13:25 USSDG`

I am the member of the group `sip` but I am not able to create any file if I access this directory using my user name. Can anyone point our any issue with this?

Specially I am concerned about the "+" sign which comes in last of it. I feel that this has something to do with the problem. What does the "+" represent in the above output?

Answer (score 6):

### Welcome to the wonderful new Unix world of 1989!

Those nice TRUSIX people have — just this year — defined an extension to the `ls` command to indicate visually when the `rwxrwxrwx` permissions information is not actually the whole of the story.  That extension is a `+` character following the permission flags.  As you can see, your `ls` output has this very `+` character.  That means that your files have these new-fangled *discretionary access control list* thingies that the TRUSIX people are so excited about.  As such, your access to the files is *not* necessarily what you can deduce from the nine permissions flags alone.

To compensate for these limitations of old-style Unix tools in the face of the new-style ACLs, the TRUSIX people have also come up with a couple of new commands, `getacl` and `setacl`.  The former is used for looking at those ACLs.  I hear murmurings that people might prefer [`getfacl`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getfacl) and [`setfacl`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl) as names.

In 20 years time, of course, nine bits of permissions will seem old-hat and passé, ACLs will be the norm, and [even lookalike operating systems of the 1990s to come will have followed where Unix has gone before](http://linux.die.net/man/5/acl). ☺

#### Further reading

- Craig Rubin (1989-08-18).  [*Rationale for Selecting Access Control List Features for the Unix System*](http://fas.org./irp/nsa/rainbow/tg020-a.htm).  NCSC-TG-020-A.  DIANE Publishing.  ISBN 9780788105548.

Answer (score 4):

Access control lists (ACL) are indicated by the +. `man getfacl` is usually a good point to start reading.